# Quick website evaluation checklist

Tags: accessibility

I want to make a small checklist to evaluate my sites.
I want to make SEO , usability and accessibility checks.

Which are the most important checks I have to make?

Answer (score 8):

I can suggest you various article on this subject:

- [Smashing magazine checklists roundup](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/29/45-incredibly-useful-web-design-checklists-and-questionnaires/)
- [Web Site Magazine](http://www.websitemagazine.com/content/blogs/posts/pages/everyday-usability-14-point-checklist-for-success.aspx)
- [Antorher very good roundup](http://bestwebdesignschools.com/2009/usabilityedu-25-incredibly-useful-usability-cheat-sheets-checklists/)
- [Boagworld checklist](http://boagworld.com/business-strategy/pre-launch-checklist)
- [Last but not least the wonderful article by Davis Travis](http://www.userfocus.co.uk/resources/guidelines.html)

Ok this a little big list but maybe you can find the right one for you, enjoy it!

Answer (score 5):

The Usability Toolkit that Bunnyfoot helped develop for COI may be of use.

- [COI Usability Toolkit](http://usability.coi.gov.uk/)